# I changed Home folder Name, without changing account name- mac doesn’t starts any more. No back up

Tags: macos, home-folder

I have changed my home folder name without changing the user account name and without any back up at all I have restarted my Mac. This was a big mistake!
Now my computer doesn’t start any more. However bootcamp system with windows is working normally.
Is there any possibility to save my data on Mac now?

I was able to make an IMAGE copy to the external hatddrive with the utility disk. Can I use this somehow?
Is there any possibility how I can solve this problem without making a completely new installation and without loosing my data?

I would appreciate it a lot if someone could help me!
Thank you!!!!

Comment: Welcome on StackExchange.
Usually MacOS doesn't let any user do this kind of renaming its own home folder.
Could you search in your memory what exactly you might have done?
Did you use another admin account?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 
The user account was the same. I just changed the name of the home folder. 
However after a long research on the internet I have almost solved the problem by creating an admin account. So I could save my data! I’m so glad about that!  At the apple support they told me that it would be impossible and I should just install everything new! It is really a shame.

Comment: The answer from the Apple support was a shame. You are right. Perhaps they didn't take enough time to ask the correct question. I am convinced you used another admin account. And this was also most probably the way to get out of **one** account locked.